# (Xamarin.Forms) Shell does not work with TabbedPage in IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage, app-shell

I'm using Shell with buttom nav and want to be able to have one of the tabs as a TabbedPage. Also one of my contentpages in Shell have a toolbar item which leads to a tabbedpage, this also does not work in iOS, but both working fine in Android.

What I mean by not working is that even though I set the background color to white, I just get a black "blank-screen", I see nothing.

I tried to create a new TabbedPage, same issue, tryed the newest 3.6 forms release and also the 4.0 beta 9pre release, still same issue.

**Update**

Here is my tabbedpage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MyApp.Page.TabbedPageTest"
        BackgroundColor="White">
   <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
   <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" BackgroundColor="White">
       <Label Text="Label in tab 1" TextColor="Orange" />
   </ContentPage>
   <ContentPage Title="Tab 2" BackgroundColor="White">
       <Label Text="Label in tab 2" TextColor="Orange" />
   </ContentPage>
   <ContentPage Title="Tab 3" BackgroundColor="White">
       <Label Text="Label in tab 3" TextColor="Orange" />
   </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Here is where I load it:

```
<ShellItem>
    <ShellSection Title="PageOne" Icon="ic_action_myicon1.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MyListView}" />
    </ShellSection>
    <ShellSection Title="PageTwo" Icon="ic_action_myicon2.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MyContentPage}" />
    </ShellSection>
    <ShellSection Title="PageThree" Icon="ic_action_myicon3.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TabbedPageTest}"/>
    </ShellSection>
</ShellItem>
```

The listview and contentPage works fine. The TabbedPage are just black from top to buttom.

Comment: Could you please give a minimal example that showcases your issue. We can't help just reading your description of the problem

Comment: Share your codes please.

Comment: I just updated my question with the code, but its very basic.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms Shell is still in preview and you can submit your feedback [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell).